# Image display not correct in Wordpress Carousel

Tags: css, wordpress

This problem concern how the images are display in Wordpress Carousel. If you click on the link below you will see a page of one of the product :

http://www.itsy-bitsy.ca/product/rice-basket/

Don't click on any picture ! In order to see where the problem is, you have to choose an option in the "Choose an option" menu.

Then, you will see that the picture on the left side won't show completely.

If you click on the picture, this one will show how it's suppose to be.

Did someone know which code line (CSS I guess) will I have to change to get things in order ?

Thanks and have a nice day...

Answer (score 0):

Find `<div class="owl-wrapper-outer autoHeight" style="height: 104px;">` and remove height:104px but this code is coming perhaps from javascript code. find that javascript code and remove it. It will resolve problem. If you got tired to find it then simply open your style.css file and add following code:

```
.owl-wrapper-outer {
   height: 619px !important;
}
```